# Question about a differentiable function at point $a$.

Tags: calculus, analysis, limits, derivatives

Let $f$ be differentiable at point $a$. Prove than if $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}x_n =\ a^{+}$ and $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}y_n = a^{-}$ then $$\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{ f(x_n) - f(y_n)}{x_n - y_n} = f'(a)$$

I thought about proving this by using lagrange's theorem, but I didn't know where to go with this because the question has *limit* and its talking about one point, not an interval.

Is there any ideas how to solve this question?

Comment: What do you mean by $\lim_{n\to+\infty} x_n=a^+$? Do you mean that all $x_n>a$? That $x_n$ is monotone?

Comment: it means that $x_n$ converges to a from the right side.

Comment: @mickep I believe that the sequence of points $x_n$ is monotone decreasing.

Comment: @FirasAliAbdelGhani are you working with $f: X \to \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Its not given in the question. but usually when its not mentioned otherwise then we are talking about $f: X \to \mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using algebraic manipulation we may write

$$\begin{align}\frac{f(x_n) - f(y_n)}{x_n - y_n} &= \frac{[f(x_n) - f(a)] - [f(y_n) - f(a)]}{x_n - y_n} = \frac{f(x_n) - f(a)}{x_n-y_n} - \frac{f(y_n) - f(a)}{x_n - y_n}\\&=\underbrace{\Bigg(\frac{x_n - a}{x_n - y_n}\Bigg)}_{t_n}\frac{f(x_n) - f(a)}{x_n-a} + \Bigg(\frac{(x_n - x_n) -(y_n - a)}{x_n - y_n}\Bigg)\frac{f(y_n) - f(a)}{y_n-a}\\&=t_n\underbrace{\frac{f(x_n) - f(a)}{x_n-a}}_{\to f'(a)} + \Big(1 - t_n\Big)\underbrace{\frac{f(y_n) - f(a)}{y_n-a}}_{\to f'(a)} \end{align}$$

Notice that $$y_n < a \Rightarrow x_n - a < x_n - y_n \Rightarrow \frac{x_n - a}{x_n - y_n} < 1$$ then the sequence $\{t_n\}$ is bounded and $0 < t_n < 1$. Then

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{f(x_n) - f(y_n)}{x_n - y_n} = \lim_{n \to \infty}t_n\underbrace{\frac{f(x_n) - f(a)}{x_n-a}}_{\to f'(a)} + \Big(1 - t_n\Big)\underbrace{\frac{f(y_n) - f(a)}{y_n-a}}_{\to f'(a)} = f'(a)$$

Answer (score 3):

Since $f$ is differentiable on $a$ then

$$f(x_n)=f(a)+(x_n-a)f'(a)+(x_n-a)\epsilon_1(x_n)$$
where $\epsilon_1(x_n)\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}0$ and similarly we have
$$f(y_n)=f(a)+(y_n-a)f'(a)+(y_n-a)\epsilon_2(y_n)$$
where $\epsilon_2(y_n)\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}0$. Now subtracting the two equalities and we get

$$f(x_n)-f(y_n)=(x_n-y_n)f'(a)+\underbrace{(x_n-a)\epsilon_1(x_n)-(y_n-a)\epsilon_2(x_n)}_{=R_n}$$

$$R_n=(x_n-y_n)\epsilon_1(x_n)+(y_n-a)(\epsilon_1(x_n)-\epsilon_2(y_n))$$
and notice that

$$0\le a-y_n=\underbrace{(a-x_n)}_{\le0}+(x_n-y_n)\le x_n-y_n$$ 
Can you take it from here?

Comment: what do you mean by $\epsilon_1$? and how did get the first line? did u use lagrange?

Comment: $\epsilon_1$ is just a notation for a function tending to $0$ when $x_n$ tends to $a$. The equality that I wrote is the definition of the differentiability of $f$ on $a$ so it's a special case of the Lagrange  formula.